# How to block or hide the inline keyboard for a certain user telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Can I somehow block the inline keyboard for a user after he clicks the button without blocking it for everyone else? I want to make a rock paper scissors game using the inline keyboard but it is possible that one user chooses two options and plays the game with themselves. I want to avoid it. Is it possible and if it is, how can I do it?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['rps']) 
def start_game(msg): 
    inline_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2) 
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Rock', callback_data='R')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Scissors', callback_data='S') 
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Paper', callback_data='P') 
    inline_markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Choose your fraction', reply_markup=inline_markup)
```

Here I am adding the keyboard and creating the buttons

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: len(call.data) == 1) 
def rps(call):
    global res, players 
    if len(res)<2: 
        res += call.data 
        player_num = 'p' + str(len(res))
        players[player_num] = call.from_user.first_name 
    if len(res) == 2: 
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.message_id, reply_markup = None)
```

In this function I am checking how many people have clicked the inline button (res and players are imported from external config but they are initially res='', players={}).
The program is meant to only let 2 users to play, but the same user can click the buttons twice and finish the game.

Comment: Please provide some code samples and where exactly you are facing the issue.

Comment: I just added some code. I hope it will be useful